# Searching a Column for common text strings

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I have a *google* form exporting to a spreadsheet and want to search a description field for the most common words or phrases. Would like to return 10 or so that aren't obvious like `"or, and, is"` etc.

I found and modified the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",'Form Responses 1'!F2:F)," ")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 10 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0))
```

But it just returns `#Value` under word and 1 under the frequency. Because I had to modify the original formula which was referencing `column B` I am concerned that the Col#'s are the issue but not sure what I am missing.

I believe the Output should return the top 10 words found and their frequency in 2 columns. I realize as currently constituted I would have to add some conditions to the Query to exclude the obvious words above but I wanted to at least get results before I started messing with that part.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pVXHU-S1zI3qRhVkLwPPASx5Nn-iNIlJ47-wuXFNhVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may come from right here `'Form Responses 1!'F2:F` If I'm not mistaken, then you're trying to grab 2 columns from a range of a single column (F). Try changing that part of the formula to `'Form Responses 1!'F2:G` (Assuming G is where the second column you want in your range is located) and see if that works.

Comment: I think you may be on to something I tried changing it to G and that did not work but when I just put =JOIN(" ",'Form Responses 1'!F2:F) it gives me a 50000 character limit error.

Comment: @JoeyLoFaro Perhaps for testing purposes then, try something like `'Form Responses 1'!F2:F100` and see what the result is. I encourage playing around with numbers like that if you haven't already, often times it helps lead to a better understanding of the code you're working with.